# Swift - no such module PureLayout with manual installation AND cocoa pods? Its impossible?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I've tried everything. EVERYTHING. I have no. idea. what Im doing wrong here.

Ive downloaded test projects and followed every step under manual installation AND install using pods here: https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout#problems-suggestions-pull-requests

I already have Parse and some other modules installed via pods so I first went to pods. I first went to my pods file and wrote

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'PureLayout'
```

JUST as the working sample projects did. I then navigated to my project (I think I did this right - went to terminal did cd Desktop then cd my project name, didn't think I had to cd anywhere else) and ran `pod install` . After this nothing happened in terminal (I got no response no matter what I did) and no PureLayout files were added to my project.

I still got no such module Purelayout when trying to trying to `import PureLayout` so then I tried manual.

I have dragged the files here https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout/tree/master/PureLayout/PureLayout into my project and imported in my bridging header:

[image]

Tell me if Im missing something. I still get no such module - even checked in my build settings that it had the right bridging header. I can continue without this and have no ideas - What am i doing wrong?

Is this an impossible problem?

Comment: Does the demo project work for you?

Comment: Yes but I can't implement it in my own projects. Nothing I do works

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm running into the same issue.